# Still can't stop the Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pycurl

I want to stop the thread with simple CTR+C, but data is keep coming and coming, so I have to close the window and start it again. Help me please to fix the issue. In order to see what I'm saying, just type your twitter username and password in user and pass

```
import threading
import random
import time
import Queue
import urllib2
import sys
import simplejson, pycurl
import sys, signal

queue = Queue.Queue()
keep_running = True
user = "" # username
pswd = "" # password
headers = [ "Content-Type: text/xml; charset: UTF-8; "]

class MyThread(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.buffer = ""
        self.streaming_url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=justinbieber"

    def start_crawl(self, user, pswd):
        self.conn = pycurl.Curl()
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (user, pswd))
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, self.streaming_url)
        #self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.READFUNCTION, self.storage)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPAUTH, pycurl.HTTPAUTH_BASIC)
        self.conn.perform()


    def storage(self, data):
        self.buffer += str(data)
        if isinstance(self.buffer, str):
            if self.buffer.endswith("\r\n") and self.buffer.strip():
                content = json.loads(self.buffer)
                self.buffer = ""
                self.queue.put(content)
                self.queue.task_done()
                #if "text" in content:
                    #print u"{0[user][name]}: {0[text]}".format(content)
        else:
            return data

    def run(self):
        while keep_running:
            self.start_crawl(user,pswd)
            if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
                sys.exit()
            #line = self.names[random.randint(0,len(self.names)-1)]
            #queue.put(line)


class Starter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue
        t = MyThread(self.queue)
        t.start()
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if not self.queue.empty():
                line = self.queue.get(timeout=0.2)
                print line, self.queue.qsize()
            else:
                print 'waiting for queue'

def main():  
    try:
        Starter()   
        queue.join()  
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        print 'Stopping'
        global keep_running
        keep_running = False
        #Join all existing threads to main thread.
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            if thread is not threading.currentThread():
                thread.join()
        sys.exit(1)

main()
```

Comment: I've tried it and it works just fine. Just hold ctrl+c pressed and if doesn't work just don't print that much data on your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the thread as daemon and it will be killed with your program

```
import threading
import random
import time
import Queue
import urllib2
import sys
import simplejson, pycurl
import sys, signal

queue = Queue.Queue()
keep_running = True
user = "" # username
pswd = "" # password
headers = [ "Content-Type: text/xml; charset: UTF-8; "]

class MyThread(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.buffer = ""
        self.streaming_url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=justinbieber"

    def start_crawl(self, user, pswd):
        self.conn = pycurl.Curl()
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (user, pswd))
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, self.streaming_url)
        #self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.READFUNCTION, self.storage)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPAUTH, pycurl.HTTPAUTH_BASIC)
        self.conn.perform()


    def storage(self, data):
        self.buffer += str(data)
        if isinstance(self.buffer, str):
            if self.buffer.endswith("\r\n") and self.buffer.strip():
                content = json.loads(self.buffer)
                self.buffer = ""
                self.queue.put(content)
                self.queue.task_done()
                #if "text" in content:
                    #print u"{0[user][name]}: {0[text]}".format(content)
        else:
            return data

    def run(self):
        while keep_running:
            self.start_crawl(user,pswd)
            if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
                sys.exit()
            #line = self.names[random.randint(0,len(self.names)-1)]
            #queue.put(line)


class Starter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue
        t = MyThread(self.queue)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if not self.queue.empty():
                line = self.queue.get(timeout=0.2)
                print line, self.queue.qsize()
            else:
                print 'waiting for queue'

def main():  
    try:
        Starter()   
        queue.join()  
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        print 'Stopping'
        raise

main()
```

Comment: Before t.start(), write t.daemon=True

Comment: I just tried the same thing and also tried to do t.setDaemon(True) but same thing...... ((( I'm running Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Did you remove the thread join in except of KeyboardInterrupt? I am on Lucid with Python 2.7